# Jenkins - use def Variable in multiple stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins variable **BUILDVERSION_DATE** in stage which is calculated and formatted correctly. Everything works perfectly.

```
script {
def now = new Date();
def inOneHour = new Date(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);
println inOneHour.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
def BUILDVERSION_DATE=inOneHour.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
 }
```

Now I would like to use this calculated variable in multiple stages (without code repetition).
I have tried to put this code into `environment {...}` section but it fails.

If it was static variable I know I can define it in environment segment.
But how this calculated variable be defined and used in multiple stages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add this value to an environment variable named `BUILDVERSION_DATE`, then you can assign it to the `env` object intrinsic to Jenkins Pipeline:

```
env.BUILDVERSION_DATE=inOneHour.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

Comment: so you are suggesting to me that I should define this in some stage with `def env.BUILDVERSION_DATE` and then it can be used on multiple stages? correct?

Comment: @AndreyDonald Based on the information provided and the literal question asked, then yes that is correct.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work:
`WorkflowScript: 49: unexpected token: env @ line 49, column 11.
         def env.BUILDVERSION_DATE=inOneHour.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))`

Comment: @AndreyDonald That is not what is in my answer. Please accurately copy and paste my answer.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I marked the answer :) Sorry one more question - did you face maybe the similar issue like this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016482/jenkins-and-jfrog-artifactory-artifacts-are-not-deleted-after-maxbuilds Thanks!