# Jenkins and JFrog Artifactory - artifacts are not deleted after "maxBuilds"

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am successfully uploading my artifacts using the JFrong plugin.
I think I have set up everything for automatic deletion once the number of builds (artifacts) is more than 5. However my artifacts are not deleted (I have them more than `maxBuilds` property). In the target repo and folder I can see higher number of artifacts than the maxBuilds. My user does have permission to delete artifact (I have tried it manually).
Did I configure everything properly? Thanks

```
        stage ('Artifactory stage') {
            steps {
                rtServer (
                    id: 'Artifactory',
                    url: 'https://artifactory.domain/artifactory',
                    credentialsId: 'test',
                    timeout: 300
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Build info stage ') {
            steps {
                rtBuildInfo (
                    maxBuilds: 5,
                    deleteBuildArtifacts: true
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Upload stage') {
            steps {
                rtUpload (
                    serverId: 'Artifactory',
                    spec: '''{
                          "files": [
                            {
                              "pattern": "arena-*.zip",
                              "target": "project/packages/"
                            }
                         ]
                    }''',
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Publish build info') {
            steps {
                rtPublishBuildInfo (
                    serverId: 'Artifactory'
                )
            }
        }
```

Log information at the end of the build...

*[Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Build info stage ) [Pipeline] rtBuildInfo [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Upload stage) [Pipeline] rtUpload [consumer_0] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.domain/artifactory/packages/arena-2022-02-07-11-31-58.zip } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Publish build info) [Pipeline] rtPublishBuildInfo Deploying build info to: https://artifactory.domain/artifactory/api/build Deploying build descriptor to: https://artifactory.domain/artifactory/api/build Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://artifactory.domain/artifactory/webapp/builds/UUEAW%20::%20ArenaWebRuf%20::%20master/81 Sending request for build retention, deleting build artifacts, max number of builds to store: 5. [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)*

Comment: It all looks correct to me. Is there any log that you can share which could help to debug the issue?

Comment: Also would be good to understand if the pipeline deletes any builds but ignores the maxBuild number or if it doesn’t delete at all.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan thanks for the update. It does not delete at all. Artifacts in the target repo and folder still exist although their count is higher than maxBuilds.
I am updating the question with log information from those relevant stages (everything looks OK to me)

Comment: Can you try adding `captureEnv: true` to rtBuildInfo closure

Comment: sure. what is this `captrueEnv` used for? I do not see explanation on JFrog link

Comment: `"To set the Build-Info object to automatically capture environment variables while downloading and uploading files, add the following to your script."` what does it mean in practice?

Comment: wooow! it seems that with this property `captrueEnv` it works!!!! can you please provide more details why and how this happened? big thanks!

Comment: I submitted an answer so the question can be marked as resolved :) And added all links that I think could be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `captureEnv: true` to `rtBuildInfo` closure:

```
rtBuildInfo (
    captureEnv: true
    maxBuilds: 5,
    deleteBuildArtifacts: true
)
```

Example [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/gradle-example/Jenkinsfile)
Doc info [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax)

> **Capturing Environment Variables**
> To set the Build-Info object to
> automatically capture environment variables while downloading and
> uploading files, add the following to your script.
> By default, environment variables names which include "password",
> "psw", "secret", "token", or "key" (case insensitive) are excluded and
> will not be published to Artifactory.